# Instantiating a new object with a closure

Tags: python, closures

I'm trying to understand if what I'm doing makes sense/is a good pattern.

Filter is a callable class,meant to filter some other class (Dataview) and return a new,filtered dataview object when called.

Naturally there's a property inside Filter which is the actual function of the specific filter (filter.funct)

I want to be able to create filters like that:

```
filterc = filterb&filtera
```

so there's this code inside my Filter class:

```
def __and__(self, other):
    assert isinstance(other, Filter),"And(Logical operation) between Filters supports only another Filter,got {}".format(type(other))
    def new_funct(dataview):
        return self(dataview)&other(dataview)
    return Filter(funct=new_funct,str_representation=repr(self)+'&'+repr(other))
```

As you can see,i'm creating a new Filter object,with some inner function I'm making,hoping that it is a closure (eg its environment in some sense is saved).

While the code itself is working, I want to know if this makes sense & if I'm doing something inherently wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with this approach: it avoids making separate classes for each kind of “compound” `Filter`.  However, one might expect a lambda:

```
return Filter(lambda x: self(x)&other(x),…)
```

That’s just syntax: it closes over `self` and `other` either way.